# How to refresh tabs in horizontal tabbed design using ajax refresh?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, jsp

I am working on a web development project in which I have designed Horizontal tabbed design and then after clicking on each tab, I am showing tables.

Currently I have only two tab in my design. As soon as I click `TEST1` tab, it shows `Table1` but if I click `TEST2` tab, it shows another table having different columns and data which is `Table2` and it works fine.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/veGY9/8/).

And here is my test4.jsp design -

```
<div id='headerDivDash'>
    <h1 id='topHeaderDash'>
        some_image
    </h1>
</div>

<ul id="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" name="tab1">TEST1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" name="tab2">TEST2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="content"> 
    <div id="tab1">
            <h2>Test 1</h2>
        <div class="container">
            <c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.machines}">
                <div class="component">
                    <h3>
                        For
                        <c:out value="${e.key}" />
                    </h3>
                    <table class="overflow-y">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>${m.fName}</th>
                                    <td class="color-changer">${m.lName}</td>
                                    <td>${m.address}</td>
                                    <td>${m.email}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
            <h2>Test 2</h2>

        <div class="container">
            <c:forEach var="e" items="${testing.machines}">
                <div class="component">
                    <h3>
                        For
                        <c:out value="${e.key}" />
                    </h3>
                    <table class="overflow-y">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="m" items="${e.value}">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>${m.fName}</th>
                                    <td class="color-changer">${m.lName}</td>
                                    <td>${m.address}</td>
                                    <td>${m.email}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </c:forEach>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">&copy Some value</div>
```

I am passing data from controller to jsp page. Now what I would like to do is -

- I would like to refresh both of my tabs which are `tab1 div` and `tab2 div` every 30 seconds using AJAX refresh. Initially, before any refresh, I would like to grey out my background and then show refresh image. After refresh is done, that refresh image will be gone and two divs `tab1 div` and `tab2 div` should get refreshed.
- Also, if I am on `TEST1` tab, and then the refresh is happening, then it should be on `TEST1` tab but suppose if I am on `TEST2` tab, and then the refresh is happening, then it should be on `TEST2` tab.

I have tried coding this as shown in my jsfiddle and below jquery which I have coded only tries to refresh `tab1 div` but somehow tab1 div is not reflecting the latest data. It is always showing the old data which I see when I hit the url for the first time. And I am not sure what wrong I am doing there?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    setInterval(refresh, 30 * 1000);
});

//Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test4.jsp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#tab1");
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('#tab1').replaceWith(content); # this is not updating my tab div with latest data
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I am not able to see that my `tab1` div is getting refreshed at all. I can see refresh image showing up but somehow tab1 always hold same old data which I see hitting the url for the first time.. Is there something wrong in my jquery?

And also how can I add refresh for both of my tabs?

**UPDATE:-**

I have noticed one thing which is pretty strange, if I remove `content div and tab1 div` and just refresh `container div` then I am able to see my updated data after refresh and it works fine but if I add `content and tab1 div` and try to refresh `container div`, then it doesn't work at all. So something is wrong for sure..

Comment: First separate the loading of data from the displaying of data - the two methods should be able to work independently. Then consider that each piece of data is only required when visible. i.e. tab is clicked: stop all refreshing. if data for this tab exists and is not older than 30s load data else show existing data. start refresh loop for this tab's data only.

Comment: @Popnoodles: Thanks for your suggestion.. Does my code is not separated out? If possible can you provide an example how would this work?

Comment: What file are you working on exactly? Or what file does the refresh ?

Comment: @Wilmer: I have everything in test4.html and in general, it's a jsp page which has all those html and jquery stuff.. So once I passing an object from controller to jsp, it should show up there.. So I have a refresh method in that test4.html (test4.jsp) page.

Comment: Well I don't see anything "wrong" with the refresh function maybe it can be simplified a little bit but that's it.

Comment: @Wilmer: Can you provide an example what can be simplified so that I can try it out may be that can help? I have noticed one thing which is pretty strange, if I remove `content div and tab1 div` and just refresh `container div` then I am able to see my updated data after refresh and it works fine but if I add content and tab1 div and try to refresh container div, then it doesn't work at all. So something is wrong for sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´ll need to wait until the data is received. But if your timer is long enough, this should not matter.

So, please change your code to something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Create overlay and append to body:
    $('<div id="overlay"/>').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        width: '100%',
        height: $(window).height() + 'px',
        opacity:0.4, 
        background: 'lightgray url(http://bradsknutson.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/page-loader.gif) no-repeat center'
    }).hide().appendTo('body');

    // Execute refresh with interval:
    refresh();
});

//Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    // Retrieve data:
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test4.html',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#tab1");
            //Replace content inside the div
            $('#tab1').replaceWith(content); # this is not updating my tab div with latest data
            // HIDE the overlay:
            $('#overlay').hide();
            setTimeout(refresh, 30 * 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

If this does not replace your data, simply 
replace this lines:

```
var content =  $($.parseHTML(data)).filter("#tab1");
//Replace content inside the div
$('#tab1').replaceWith(content); # this is not updating my tab div with latest data
// HIDE the overlay:
$('#overlay').hide();
setTimeout(refresh, 30 * 1000);
```

With this:

```
$('#tab1').html(data);
$('#overlay').hide();
setTimeout(refresh, 30 * 1000);
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion but with that approach my refresh image is always shown on my screen, it's not going at all somehow.. Any thoughts? And in your second suggestion, it will load everything right including the headers and footers as well?

Comment: I can´t say why it´s always displaying the refresh image on screen without any code. My second solution includes all received data to the specified element. If you don´t want all please cut off the <head> section, or send the body data via json to it. Then just call something like `data.body`. `body` is e. g. the json key which inlcudes the html inside the <body> tag.

Answer (score 0):

As requested you can try replace the ajax request with the following equivalent:

```
//Create a refresh function:
function refresh(){
    // SHOW overlay
    $('#overlay').show();
    $('#tab1').load('test4.jsp #tab1', function(){
        // HIDE the overlay:
        $('#overlay').hide();
    });
}
```